# Correctly interpreting the Second Borel-Cantelli Lemma in a coin toss problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $H_{n}$ denote the outcome of the $n$-th trial of flipping a coin. Suppose $P(H_{n}=0)=\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$ for $n = 1,2, \cdots$. I need to determine the probability of observing infinitely many heads.

Now, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(H_{n}=0) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin \left( \frac{1}{n}\right)$.

I was able to show by limit comparison with the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin \left( \frac{1}{n}\right) = \infty$.

And since each coin toss is independent, I can apply the Second Borel-Cantelli 
Lemma, which states as follows:

> For a sequence of mutually independent events $A_{1},A_{2},\cdots, $
>   $$P\left(\limsup_{n \to \infty}A_{n} \right) = 1, \, \text{whenever} \, \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}P(A_{i})=\infty.$$

So, let's denote $A_{n}:=\,\{\text{event where}\,H_{n}=0\}$.

Then, what I think the Lemma is saying is that the probability of $H_{n}=0$ is $1$. And since $H_{n}=0$ is the probability of zero heads (I think), then the probability of infinitely many heads would be $1-P(A_{n}) = 0$. Is this correct?

I'm a little confused about this...

Comment: No, you know $P[A_n]=P[H_n=0] = \sin(1/n)$ (as given info).  Borel-Cantelli says (i) if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[A_i] < \infty$ then with prob 1 only a finite number of the events will occur, (ii) if $\{A_i\}$ are mutually independent and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} P[A_i] = \infty$ then with prob 1 an infinite number of the events will occur.

Comment: @Michael So $P(\limsup_{n \to \infty}A_{n}) = 1$ is the same thing as saying that it is with probability $1$ that an infinite number of the events $H_{n}=0$ will occur? But, is $P(H_{n}=0)$ the probability of heads or tails?

Comment: The coin toss has outcomes 0/1, which binary value you assign to "heads" and "tails" is arbitrary.  The limsup of a sequence of sets $\{A_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is defined $$ \limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} A_n = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} \cup_{i=n}^{\infty} A_i $$ Intuitively, $\cup_{i=n}^{\infty}A_i$ is the event that at least one of the events $\{A_n, A_{n+1}, ...\}$ holds true, and taking an intersection of these means that no matter how big your index $n$, at least one of the events $A_i$ with $i>n$ will be true (and so an infinite number of the events will be true).

Comment: "But, is P(Hn=0) the probability of heads or tails?" It is up to you to  say so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lemma applied to $H_n=0$ states that for almost all coins, a tail occurs infinitely often.

Note that $P[H_n = 1] = 1-\sin {1 \over n}$ and
$\sum_n P[H_n = 1] = \infty$, so that for almost all coins, a head will occur infinitely often as well.